# suspendCancellableCoroutine returns CompletedWithCancellation instead of the actual type

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I ran into a weird issue that manifested itself when I updated the `kotlinx-coroutines-core` dependency from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3. However, the self-contained example below reproduces the issue with 1.3.2 as well.

I have an extension method for a callback-based operation queue. This extension method uses `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to wrap the callback usage and to convert it to a suspend function. Now, it all works otherwise, but the resulting object that is returned from the suspending function is not of type `T`, but `CompletedWithCancellation<T>`, which is a private class of the coroutine library.

The weird thing is, if I call `c.resume("Foobar" as T, {})` inside the `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, it works just fine. When using the callback routine, the value is a `String` before passing to to `c.resume()`, but it gets wrapped in a `CompletedWithCancellation` object.

Here's the code that reproduces the issue:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        vm.liveData.observe(this, Observer {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mainText).text = "Got result: $it"
        })

        vm.getFoo()
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val manager = OperationManager()
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getFoo() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val op = Operation(manager, "Foobar")
            val rawResult = op.get<Any>()
            Timber.d("Raw result: $rawResult")

            val op2 = Operation(manager, "Foobar")
            val result = op2.get<String>()
            Timber.d("Casted result: $result")
            liveData.postValue(result)
        }
    }
}

class OperationManager {
    private val operationQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Operation>()
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val operationRunnable = Runnable { startOperations() }

    private fun startOperations() {
        val iter = operationQueue.iterator()
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            val operation = iter.next()
            operationQueue.remove(operation)
            Timber.d("Executing operation $operation")
            operation.onSuccess(operation.response)
        }
    }

    fun run(operation: Operation) {
        addToQueue(operation)
        startDelayed()
    }

    private fun addToQueue(operation: Operation) {
        operationQueue.add(operation)
    }

    private fun startDelayed() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(operationRunnable)
        handler.post(operationRunnable)
    }
}

open class Operation(private val manager: OperationManager, val response: Any) {

    private val listeners = mutableListOf<OperationListener>()

    fun addListener(listener: OperationListener) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun execute() = manager.run(this)
    fun onSuccess(data: Any) = listeners.forEach { it.onResult(data) }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
suspend fun <T> Operation.get(): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { c ->

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val callback = object : OperationListener {
        override fun onResult(result: Any) {
            Timber.d("get().onResult() -> $result")
            c.resume(result as T, {})
        }
    }

    addListener(callback)
    execute()
}

interface OperationListener {
    fun onResult(result: Any)
}
```

Do note that just before calling `c.resume()`, the type of `result` is `String`, as it should be. However, it's not `String` in `getFoo()` once the suspend function completes. What causes this?

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1966

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in this:

```
c.resume(result as T)
```

Instead of:

```
c.resume(result as T, {})
```

It seems that the former handles the execution of `resume()` correctly after `getResult()` is called, whereas the latter only works if `resume()` is called before `getResult()`.